# SSH Connection to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, ssh

I am a layman and I am not sure if I understand correctly how does an SSH connection to a MySQL DB work.

Shown below you find a screenshot of a common GUI used to set-up the connection in object.

I understand that I need to insert the MySQL Server IP, the port, my user and password in order to connect to the SQL DB. But I do not fully understand why I need to provide a SSH Server IP address, user and password.

If I am able to connect to a MySQL Server using a direct SSH connection, why would I need to mention an SSH Server (another machine)?

Does the SSH Server act as an intermediary? If so why and how? Could you help me understand?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: The SSH server acts as an intermediate destination and, in this case, like a single-purpose VPN or tunnel.

Comment: Do you mean that there is a secure ssh tunnel from my laptop to the SSH Server and that I access the MySQL Server with the IP of the SSH Server? And, if I get it, what is the purpose of having such intermediate destination?

Comment: It's usually because your destination has a firewall and the only way through the firewall is SSH.